# Is this PHP snippet equivalent to the C# snippet?

Tags: c#, php, cryptography, sha256, hmac

We're given [this C# snippet](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/1qwwabj) which generates some string to be used in a Rest API call.

We have to implement it in PHP. The client also provides us with a PHP snippet, but the string returned by PHP is different than the one returned by C#. Would you be able to tell what's wrong? I need the PHP snippet to give the same output as C#.

Here's the [PHP snippet](https://www.onlinegdb.com/aGcvGLtRj)

I'll share the functions here  as well, it might be easier for you to read

C#

```
public static string CalculateDigest(string publicKey, string privateKey, string message)
{
    var digest = "";
    var hash = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey));
    var correctHash = string.Join(string.Empty, hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
    digest = publicKey + ":" + correctHash;
    return digest;
}
```

PHP

```
$digest = $PUBLIC_KEY.":".Hash_hmac("sha256", $message, $PRIVATE_KEY);
```

Comment: (Note use, `string.Concat(...)` rather than `string.Join(string.Empty, ...)`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$PUBLIC_KEY = "1";
$message = "2";
$PRIVATE_KEY = "3";
$digest = $PUBLIC_KEY.":".hash_hmac("sha256", $message, $PRIVATE_KEY);
echo $digest;
?>
```

And,

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(CalculateDigest("1", "3", "2"));
}


public static string CalculateDigest(string publicKey, string privateKey, string message)
{
    var digest = "";
    var hash = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey));
    var correctHash = string.Join(string.Empty, hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
    digest = publicKey + ":" + correctHash;
    return digest;
}
```

These 2 pieces of code give the same output.(Which is, `1:b7648703c8f81cdc99f58e9f0214874fdaeedec81d83492799537fd0231b70d4`)

Looking at the snippets you provided, some of the data are not same. (i.e. executeInitialPaymentNow variable is true in php snippet and false in C# one). Please make sure the final string you are supplying to the hashing functions are identical.

Message variable in C# snippet:

> Customer-746508130245354364190340483PSW2017-11-28 10:15:350ZfalsePSWtestfalse2017-11-28 10:15:350Z2017-12-04 10:15:350Ztrue1

Message variable in PHP snippet:

> Customer-746508130245354364190340483PSW2017-11-28 10:15:350ZtruePSW360VUZCatQATVodafonetrue2017-11-28 10:15:350Z2017-12-04 10:15:350Ztrue1truetrue